People Api has not been used in this project
I'm trying to authenticate with google in a Flutter Web project, and I have something like this
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: <String>[
          'email',
      ],
  );

  Future<void> test() async {
      try {
          await _googleSignIn.signOut();
          GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      } catch (e) {
          print(e);
      }
  }

I'm just doing so and Google pop up appears, but when I select account I receive this response
{"access_token":"<redacted>","token_type" 
:"Bearer","expires_in":3598,"scope":"email profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","authuser":"0","prompt":"none"}

and this error
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Trying to set gapi client token.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the 
gapi.client library is not loaded in your page.

ClientException: {
 "error": {
 "code": 403,
 "message": "People API has not been used in project proyectId before or it is 
disabled. Enable it by visiting
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/overview? 
project=proyectId then retry. If you
enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our 
systems and retry.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
    "links": [
      {
        "description": "Google developers console API activation",
        "url": 
"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/overview? 
 project=proyectId"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "service": "people.googleapis.com",
      "consumer": "projects/proyectId"
    }
   }
  ]
  }
 }

I already added meta tag in index.html
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="googleProyectId" />
So i dont know if I'm missing something

Are you still getting the same message even after enabling the People API in your Google Cloud Console?

Reading the docs, i realize that in Flutter Web the signIn method should not be used and will be deprecated, it is better to use a mix of signInSilently method, but it sometimes fails if user closes it once and it doesn't open anymore (for security i guess).
Another way they recommend it's to use their renderButton, it works, but it's not customizable.
In my case, I'm using Firebase, so i did it this way
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(GoogleAuthProvider());

Of course i need to have previous firebase config.
However, i think that they should improve a real alternative for signIn()
